# how to extract rar format file on Mac?

Tags: macos, archiving, extract, rar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an app or script that will extract .rar files for Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/120481/is-there-an-app-or-script-that-will-extract-rar-files-for-mac-os-x)
>   [What’s a good way to extract .rar files on the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac)

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I am wondering how to extract rar compressed format file on Mac? Better free or open source software.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will unpack RAR format. You'll have to scroll down a bit in the downloads page for the Mac downloads.