# Universal command line unarchiving tool on a Mac

Tags: macos, archiving, extract, command-line

Is there some command line tool which allows extracting files **from most known archive types**? Something like StuffIt Expander, but without gui.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) has two command line utilities since version 2.5 according to the website:

> Supported file formats include Zip, Tar-GZip, Tar-BZip2, RAR, 7-zip, LhA, StuffIt and many other more and less obscure formats. [..] If you have a compressed file that The Unarchiver does not open, please post a bug on the [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/issues/list), and include the file in question, and I will look into whether it is possible to add support for it!
>
> [..]
>
> There are now two command-line utilities available, `unar` and `lsar`, which can be used to unpack and list archives, respectively. They are still in development and not really feature-complete, but they should work. These are available as precompiled binaries for both OS X and Windows on the [download page](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/downloads/list), and can also be built on Linux.

To download the command line tools (not included in the regular The Unarchiver download!), go to [the project's google code downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/downloads/list) and select `unar0.2.zip` (works as of September 20, 2010).

UPDATE: Use Homebrew to install the command line version of the Unarchiver:

```
brew install unar
unar my_archive.rar
```

Comment: Nice! And it supports many formats, just like asked for.

Comment: I can't find CLI there.

Comment: tig: You mean you were not able to click on "download page" in the second paragraph nicely quoted by Arjan above and on "unar0.2.zip" there? Because it works fine for me.

Comment: @tig, following the link Daniel referenced, see "unar0.2.zip, unar and lsar command-line utilities for Mac OS X 0.2 (beta version)". Yes, odd that a creator of unzip-software distributes its own software in zip format. ;-) After unzipping, there is a little bit of help using `./unar --help` and `./lsar --help`

Comment: added download information to the reply

Comment: @Arjan: Not very odd, as both win and mac can unarchive zip files without third-party apps

Comment: @Arjan, @Daniel Beck: Sorry, something with my eyes :) Seems to be the best tool

Comment: Anything that supports creating archives as well? Unar is great for unarchiving, liking it so far.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `brew install unar` or `brew install atool` and then:

```
unar archive.gz
# or
atool -x archive.gz
```

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), you can install `atool` and extract many archive types like so:

```
brew install atool
atool -x archive.anything
```

Assuming the corresponding external programs are available on your system, it can handle:

`.tar.gz`, `.tgz`, `.tar.bz`, `.tbz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.tbz2`, `.tar.Z`, `.tZ`, `.tar.lzo`, `.tzo`, `.tar.lz`, `.tlz`, `.tar.xz`, `.txz`, `.tar.7z`, `.t7z`, `.tar`, `.zip`, `.jar`, `.war`, `.rar`, `.lha`, `.lzh`, `.7z`, `.alz`, `.ace`, `.a`, `.arj`, `.arc`, `.rpm`, `.deb`, `.cab`, `.gz`, `.bz`, `.bz2`, `.gz`, `.bz`, `.bz2`, `.Z`, `.lzma`, `.lzo`, `.lz`, `.xz`, `.rz`, `.lrz`, `.7z`, `.cpio`

> **[`atool`](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/)** is a script for managing file archives of various types (tar, tar+gzip, zip etc).
>
> The main command is `aunpack` which extracts files from an archive. Did you ever extract files from an archive, not checking whether the files were located in a subdirectory or in the top directory of the archive, resulting in files scattered all over the place? `aunpack` overcomes this problem by first extracting to a new directory. If there was only a single file in the archive, that file is moved to the original directory. `aunpack` also prevents local files from being overwritten by mistake.
>
> The other commands provided are `apack` (to create archives), `als` (to list files in archives), and `acat` (to extract files to standard out). As `atool` invokes external programs to handle the archives, not all commands may be supported for a certain type of archives.
>
> `atool` identifies archives by their file extension. Sometimes this is not possible - for instance rar archives usually have varying numeric file extensions. In those cases when `atool` can't identify the format, `file` is used instead. (`atool` can be configured not to use file.)

Comment: It is also available through macports not only through homebrew and it is also possible to build from source

Comment: MacPorts: `sudo port install atool`

Answer (score 4):

Try [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).  In addition to its own native format (.7z) it can handle the following extensions: ZIP, gzip, bzip2, tar and, in betas for version 9, xz.  It can also decompress (only) in the following formats: ARJ, CAB, CHM, cpio, DEB, DMG, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MSI, NSIS, RAR, RPM, UDF, WIM, XAR and Z.

A Windows command line version `7za.exe` is included. For other platforms, a POSIX version named `p7zip` is available from [the P7ZIP SourceForge project](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), and some of those ports are also linked from [7-Zip's download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). Unfortunately, the Mac link seems broken, so for OS X, either [build it yourself](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/) or [use MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=p7zip).

EDIT: For non-Windows versions go to the Downloads page.  There you can find the source as well as pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: Windows only, as far as I know. The question asks for command line tools for a Mac.

Comment: @Arjan: found POSIX version [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) and it there is macport for it

Comment: @tig, I merged your comment into Joe's answer. However, I do NOT know if `p7zip` supports all formats that 7-Zip does. If anyone happens to know of a binary download link then let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately, p7zip does not fully handle archives created on mac (with specially named files storing forks and other extra stuff)

Answer (score 2):

For the compression and archiving types that Mac OS X knows natively, you can just use `open`, and it'll invoke "Archive Utility" (formerly BOMArchiveHelper), just like double-clicking it from the Finder would have. This works for [pk]zip, gzip, bzip, bzip2, tar, pax, cpio, compress (.Z), etc. etc.

If you have apps installed that know how to unarchive other formats, and they have registered for those file extensions or `magic(5)` values, then the `open` command will launch those apps to handle those types. Of course you'll probably end up in those apps' GUIs.

Comment: That is what I am using now, but it has some disadvantages: I can't specify options like extracting to specific folder, application window is popping out (even if I run it with `-g`, it is still under frontmost window)

Answer (score 0):

## Arc: Cross-Platform Archiver (CLI)

[Arc](https://github.com/mholt/archiver) handles a bunch of common formats and is written in pure Go, so it works on Linux and Windows as well.

See https://webinstall.dev/arc for cross-platform installer or https://github.com/mholt/archiver for the Go library.

```bsh
curl -sS https://webinstall.dev/arc | bash
arc unarchive example.tar.xz
```

Supported formats (as of v3.5.0)

```
    The format of the archive is determined by its
    file extension*. Supported extensions:
      .zip
      .tar
      .tar.br
      .tbr
      .tar.gz
      .tgz
      .tar.bz2
      .tbz2
      .tar.xz
      .txz
      .tar.lz4
      .tlz4
      .tar.sz
      .tsz
      .zst
      .tar.zst
      .rar (open only)
      .bz2
      .gz
      .lz4
      .sz
      .xz
```