# How to open/extract rar on Mac via Terminal/Finder?

Tags: macos, rar

Lots of previous answers (including the top one on google) are only applicable to older macOS, referencing old software that is no longer available or signed. I can't answer old questions since they are now locked. The top answer also doesn't refer to the CLI version.

The rar case is special because `p7zip` from homebrew doesn't work with rar.

https://theunarchiver.com/ is well known but afaik it's GUI only. I want to be able to automate extraction.

This post will apply to modern macOS, including Apple Silicon and ARM64.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Universal command line unarchiving tool on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/190053/universal-command-line-unarchiving-tool-on-a-mac) Also [How can I extract .rar files on the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/how-can-i-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac) both of which have The Unarchiver as the top answer.

Comment: Yours is the same question. You can add your own answer to that other question to help others out, and to keep the information in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal:

With homebrew installed: https://brew.sh/

```
brew install unar
unar my_archive.rar
```

This is the CLI version of https://theunarchiver.com/ a great GUI app to use directly in finder, available from the website or app store directly.